# Dealing with well-formed but invalid dates in PHP DateTime

Tags: php, validation, date, datetime

I'm trying to use PHP's DateTime to validate dates, but DateTime will accept some well-formed but invalid dates like `2015-02-30`, which it will turn into `March 2, 2015`, without throwing an exception. Any suggestions for dealing with this, using DateTime or another method?

Edit: Thank you all for the help! I was handling the errors by catching the exception, but I didn't realize that the exception was only thrown on an error, not a warning, and this kind of input only kicks out a warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the errors with `DateTime::getLastErrors()`.  A well formed but invalid date:

```
$date = '2015-02-30';
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);

$errors = DateTime::getLastErrors();
print_r($errors);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [warning_count] => 1
    [warnings] => Array
        (
            [10] => The parsed date was invalid
        )

    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Whereas a non well formed date `$date = '02-30';` yields:

```
Array
(
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 1
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [5] => Data missing
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`checkdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) to check if the date is valid before using `DateTime()`:

```
$parts = explode('-', '2015-02-30'); 
if (checkdate($parts[1], $parts[2], $parts[0])) {
    // DateTime() stuff here
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/375781)